# Inconsistent Results in Multi threading Program

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I am working on a search program that searches through folders in a directory named 064, 065, 066, etc. until 069. It worked fine.

I made the main class a Runnable, and then set up two threads, each with the Search class, and some files to search through. The search results become inconsistent at best. I passed in 2 directories (P064, P065) to one thread, and 2 directories (P067 and P069) to the other one, and every time, I get a different number of search results.

The searching and output seem to work fine.

I've tried to add synchronization, which works, but then it just runs the 1st thread, and then the second thread, which is no different from no multi threading at all. When the method is given the synchronized keyword, the results are outputted correctly & consistently. It puzzles me as to why it would even need synchronization, because each thread is accessing different files in the first place.

Thanks for the help :)

If the actual number of results is 43, sometimes I get 41, 42, 55, 39, etc. Sometimes there are results outputted that are not valid, and sometimes there are missing results.

```
Runnable printA =  new patKeySearch1(files1, 1, "Terms");
Runnable printB =  new patKeySearch1(files2, 1, "(Terms");
Thread thread1 = new Thread(printA);
Thread thread2 = new Thread(printB);
thread1.start();
thread2.start();


class patKeySearch1 implements Runnable{
    File[] files;
    int number;
    String terms;
    PrintWriter writer;

    public patKeySearch1(File[] files4,int num1,String searches) throws IOException, EvalError {


//      //array of all files in the directory
        files = files4;
        number = num1;
        terms = searches;

        writer = new PrintWriter("results.txt", "UTF-8");


    }
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{


    }

//this method is where all the searching goes on
    synchronized public void showFiles(File[] files, int numField, String terms) throws IOException, EvalError{
```

}

```
@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {


        showFiles(files, number, terms);



    } catch (IOException | EvalError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the code as well?

Comment: @HarshalParekh it is quite long, what should I do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @HarshalParekh posted.

Comment: Are you combining the search results in a shared list? Did you make sure that list is thread-safe, either by wrapping it in `Collections.synchronizedList(list)` or by using a concurrent list?

Comment: @Andreas Nope, I am printing the print writer immediately when it finds a result.

Comment: You're having each thread write to the same file using different PrintWriters? At the same time? That's wrong.

Comment: @Andreas Nope, I've tested with a static printwriter and with two different printwriters with different file. As I said, the output and searching is not the problem. Thanks :)

Comment: In the code shown, you're creating a new PrintWriter in the constructor of the Runnable class, so either you're creating a PrintWriter for each thread, or all your threads are using the same Runnable, which means they are sharing fields that aren't thread-safe. In either case you have thread-safety issues.

Comment: @Andreas the printwriter is not the problem, I understand what you are saying and that appears that way due to testing. Please help with the rest of the code. Don't the first two lines show that there are two runnables by the way??

Comment: You seem to have thread-safety issues, and that would be in the `showFiles` method, but since you're hiding that method, how did you expect us to help you?

Comment: What do you mean by inconsistent results? Printing filenames in the order different from singlethreaded version? Then that is expected behavior.